Integrate .model file with android studio
I have a .model file from Weka and I want to integrate it with my Android studio. I am using Kotlin for building my app. I have no idea how to begin and what steps to follow.
I have googled and different suggestions are coming like convert .model to pmml and then put in the assets folder. But I am confused about where to begin with
